# How to parse xml file from haml(view) page to rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How to parse xml file from haml(view) page to rails controller? do i need to create model for that? if possible could you share me sample code of view and controller how form is posted and retrieve the same form in controller. Thanks for comments in advance.

Comment: The user uploads XML? As file or via input area?

Comment: [A guide to uploading files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)

Comment: As file only for example i have view page(haml) as,

  = simple_form_for(@conn, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal',:multipart => true }, :url  => file_upload_controller_path) do |f|
    = f.file_field :my_file
    = f.submit 'Upload'

and controller code,

  def file_upload
    require 'fileutils'
    tmp = params[:file_upload][:my_file].tempfile
    file = File.join("public", params[:file_upload][:my_file].original_filename)
    FileUtils.cp tmp.path, file
  end
but i am getting error(uninitialized constant PagesController)

PS:we are using ActiveResource as base class for all models

Comment: your error is because a controller is missing. Do you have a `PagesController`?

Comment: I coulldn't find PagesController in my project ( i checked in \app\controllers\ directory)

Comment: Then you need to find out where you are referencing it. Rails does a lot by default. So if other things are called `Page` - for example a model - it may deduct that that there should be a `PagesController`. `routes.rb` may be a good starting point.